# Get Cummulative Unique Contacts

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering how to go about returning number of unique contact added on a daily basis

```
    leads       callDates
    000125324   2020-04-01
    00059926437 2020-04-01
    00040129160 2020-04-01
    00041834922 2020-04-01
    00057585341 2020-04-01
...               ...        ...
    00055846603 2020-04-27
    00042104902 2020-04-27
    00049923128 2020-04-27
    00092871326 2020-04-27
    0003642000  2020-04-27
```

Assuming I have a list of leads that keeps growing on a daily basis and there is a possibility of lead duplication, how do I keep track of growth of only unique lead values in my list over time?

*Expected Output*

```
    callDate  leadsGrowth 
    2020-04-01      2
    2020-04-02      4
    2020-04-03      5
    2020-04-04      5
```

where leadsGrowth is the sum of unique leads from preceding/days plus any new leads added today.

Comment: Can there be more than 1 leads per day?

Comment: @jezrael, yes more less

Comment: @TitoLulu - Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? Add mainly duplicated datetimes.

Comment: OK, so  I think solution bellow should working nice.

Comment: I think it was quite obvious from the question statement @jezrael , not a simple cumsum dupe. Also I had already answered the question

Comment: @yatu - ya, I am sorry.

Comment: Please update your question with the new data sample you've provided, which makes it much clearer

Comment: Please add the expected output too for the new example so I can update my answer too

Comment: @yatu thanks this was the closest solution to what I was looking for